# RethinkDB Multiple emits in Map

Tags: mapreduce, rethinkdb

I've been trying out RethinkDB for a while and i still don't know how to do something like this MongoDB example:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/#calculate-order-and-total-quantity-with-average-quantity-per-item

In Mongo, in the map function, I could iterate over an array field of one document, and emit multiple values.

I don't know how to set the key to emit in map or return more than one value per document in the map function.

For example, i would like to get from this:

```
{
'num' : 1,
'lets': ['a','b,'c']
}
```

to

```
[
{'num': 1, 'let' : 'a' }, 
{'num': 1, 'let' : 'b' },
{'num': 1, 'let' : 'c' }
]
```

I'm not sure if I should think this differently in RethinkDB or use something different from map-reduce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mongo; addressing your transformation example directly:

```js
r.expr({
  'num' : 1,
  'lets': ['a', 'b', 'c']
})
.do(function(row) {
  return row('lets').map(function(l) {
    return r.object(
      'num', row('num'),
      'let', l  
    )   
  })
})
```

You can, of course, use `map()` instead of `do()` (in case not a singular object)

Comment: Oh ok, so the idea is to use a double map. And i guess I could then group based on some field before the reduce to accomplish the same thing as in mongo for the grouping for the reduce. Thanks!